# Connect asset twig function with js variable

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

Hello someone know how to connect asset function with js variable?
I have something like that `src="{{ asset('bundles/memes/uploads/') }}"`, and i want to connect this with `data['type']`. I want in result:

```
src="{{ asset('bundles/memes/uploads/#here value of js variable#') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript cannot interact directly with server-side languages, since it runs on the user web-browser using the response from the server (basic architecture).

But you can load whatever you want dynamically using something like this:

```
<img id="myImg" src="loading-img.gif" />

<script>
document.getElementById("myImg").src = "{{ absolute_url('bundles/memes/uploads/') }}" + data['type'];
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to add the image dynamically after downloading `data['type']`

Comment: What do you mean with "downloading `data['type']`"? Downloading in your upload folder or just fetching a filename?

Comment: I got this. 
I decided to use a plain path instead of the asset function.`src="../../../web/bundles/memes/uploads/'+ data['media'] +'"`.But thanks

Comment: No problem, but that's exactly what I stated in my answer!